# How do I subset Pandas dataframe rows based on indices that match the column names of another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to keep the rows in `df` only if their indices correspond with the `meth_clin` column names.

```
meth_clin = meth_clin.sort_index()
subtype = pd.DataFrame(meth_clin["subtype"])
subtype = subtype.T
subtype.columns = subtype.columns.str[:-1]

i = meth_clin.iloc[:,7:].columns.str.split("|").str[0]
i = [ j for j in i if "?" not in j ]

a = df[df.columns.intersection(subtype.columns)]
b = df[df.index.intersection(i)]
b
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_27/3481474400.py in <module>
      1 # Keep only columns of df that has clin_type info
      2 a = df[df.columns.intersection(subtype.columns)]
----> 3 b = df[df.index.intersection(i)]
      4 b

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3462             if is_iterator(key):
   3463                 key = list(key)
-> 3464             indexer = self.loc._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis=1)[1]
   3465 
   3466         # take() does not accept boolean indexers

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
   1315 
   1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1372                 if use_interval_msg:
   1373                     key = list(key)
-> 1374                 raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())

KeyError: "None of [Index(['ARID3A', 'ARID5B', 'ARNT', 'ARNT2', 'ATF3', 'ATOH8', 'BARX2', 'BATF',\n       'BATF2', 'BATF3',\n       ...\n       'ZNF697', 'ZNF714', 'ZNF771', 'ZNF775', 'ZNF787', 'ZNF789', 'ZNF83',\n       'ZNF837', 'ZNF844', 'ZNF853'],\n      dtype='object', length=251)] are in the [columns]"
```

Data:

`df.index`

```
Index(['ARID3A', 'ARID3A1', 'ARID5B', 'ARID5B1', 'ARNT', 'ARNT1', 'ARNT2',
       'ARNT21', 'ARNT211', 'ARNT22',
       ...
       'ZNF7752', 'ZNF787', 'ZNF789', 'ZNF7891', 'ZNF83', 'ZNF837', 'ZNF8371',
       'ZNF844', 'ZNF8441', 'ZNF853'],
      dtype='object', length=594)
```

`i`

```
['A1BG',
 'A1CF',
 'A2BP1',
 'A2LD1',
 'A2ML1',
 'A2M',
 'A4GALT',
 'A4GNT',
 'AAA1',
 'AAAS',
 'AACSL',
 'AACS',
 'AADACL2',
 'AADACL3',
 'AADACL4',
 'AADAC',
 'AADAT',
 'AAGAB',
 'AAK1',
 'AAMP',
 'AANAT',
 'AARS2',
 'AARSD1',
 'AARS',
 'AASDHPPT',
 'AASDH',
 'AASS',
 'AATF',
 'AATK',
 'ABAT',
 'ABCA10',
 'ABCA11P',
 'ABCA12',
 'ABCA13',
 'ABCA17P',
 'ABCA1',
 'ABCA2',
 'ABCA3',
 'ABCA4',
 'ABCA5',
 'ABCA6',
 'ABCA7',
 'ABCA8',
 'ABCA9',
 'ABCB10',
 'ABCB11',
 'ABCB1',
 'ABCB4',
 'ABCB5',
 'ABCB6',
 'ABCB7',
 'ABCB8',
 'ABCB9',
 'ABCC10',
 'ABCC11',
 'ABCC12',
 'ABCC13',
 'ABCC1',
 'ABCC2',
 'ABCC3',
 'ABCC4',
 'ABCC5',
 'ABCC6P1',
 'ABCC6P2',
 'ABCC6',
 'ABCC8',
 'ABCC9',
 'ABCD1',
 'ABCD2',
 'ABCD3',
 'ABCD4',
 'ABCE1',
 'ABCF1',
 'ABCF2',
 'ABCF3',
 'ABCG1',
 'ABCG2',
 'ABCG4',
 'ABCG5',
 'ABCG8',
 'ABHD10',
 'ABHD11',
 'ABHD12B',
 'ABHD12',
 'ABHD13',
 'ABHD14A',
 'ABHD14B',
 'ABHD15',
 'ABHD1',
 'ABHD2',
 'ABHD3',
 'ABHD4',
 'ABHD5',
 'ABHD6',
 'ABHD8',
 'ABI1',
 'ABI2',
 'ABI3BP',
 'ABI3',
 'ABL1',
 'ABL2',
 'ABLIM1',
 'ABLIM2',
 'ABLIM3',
 'ABO',
 'ABP1',
 'ABRA',
 'ABR',
 'ABT1',
 'ABTB1',
 'ABTB2',
 'ACAA1',
 'ACAA2',
 'ACACA',
 'ACACB',
 'ACAD10',
 'ACAD11',
 'ACAD8',
 'ACAD9',
 'ACADL',
 'ACADM',
 'ACADSB',
 'ACADS',
 'ACADVL',
 'ACAN',
 'ACAP1',
 'ACAP2',
 'ACAP3',
 'ACAT1',
 'ACAT2',
 'ACBD3',
 'ACBD4',
 'ACBD5',
 'ACBD6',
 'ACBD7',
 'ACCN1',
 'ACCN2',
 'ACCN3',
 'ACCN4',
 'ACCN5',
 'ACCSL',
 'ACCS',
 'ACD',
 'ACE2',
 'ACER1',
 'ACER2',
 'ACER3',
 'ACE',
 'ACHE',
 'ACIN1',
 'ACLY',
 'ACMSD',
 'ACN9',
 'ACO1',
 'ACO2',
 'ACOT11',
 'ACOT12',
 'ACOT13',
 'ACOT1',
 'ACOT2',
 'ACOT4',
 'ACOT6',
 'ACOT7',
 'ACOT8',
 'ACOT9',
 'ACOX1',
 'ACOX2',
 'ACOX3',
 'ACOXL',
 'ACP1',
 'ACP2',
 'ACP5',
 'ACP6',
 'ACPL2',
 'ACPP',
 'ACPT',
 'ACRBP',
 'ACRC',
 'ACRV1',
 'ACR',
 'ACSBG1',
 'ACSBG2',
 'ACSF2',
 'ACSF3',
 'ACSL1',
 'ACSL3',
 'ACSL4',
 'ACSL5',
 'ACSL6',
 'ACSM1',
 'ACSM2A',
 'ACSM2B',
 'ACSM3',
 'ACSM4',
 'ACSM5',
 'ACSS1',
 'ACSS2',
 'ACSS3',
 'ACTA1',
 'ACTA2',
 'ACTBL2',
 'ACTB',
 'ACTC1',
 'ACTG1',
 'ACTG2',
 'ACTL6A',
 'ACTL6B',
 'ACTL7A',
 'ACTL7B',
 'ACTL8',
 'ACTL9',
 'ACTN1',
 'ACTN2',
 'ACTN3',
 'ACTN4',
 'ACTR10',
 'ACTR1A',
 'ACTR1B',
 'ACTR2',
 'ACTR3B',
 'ACTR3C',
 'ACTR3',
 'ACTR5',
 'ACTR6',
 'ACTR8',
 'ACTRT1',
 'ACTRT2',
 'ACVR1B',
 'ACVR1C',
 'ACVR1',
 'ACVR2A',
 'ACVR2B',
 'ACVRL1',
 'ACY1',
 'ACY3',
 'ACYP1',
 'ACYP2',
 'ADAD1',
 'ADAD2',
 'ADAL',
 'ADAM10',
 'ADAM11',
 'ADAM12',
 'ADAM15',
 'ADAM17',
 'ADAM18',
 'ADAM19',
 'ADAM20',
 'ADAM21P1',
 'ADAM21',
 'ADAM22',
 'ADAM23',
 'ADAM28',
 'ADAM29',
 'ADAM2',
 'ADAM30',
 'ADAM32',
 'ADAM33',
 'ADAM3A',
 'ADAM5P',
 'ADAM6',
 'ADAM7',
 'ADAM8',
 'ADAM9',
 'ADAMDEC1',
 'ADAMTS10',
 'ADAMTS12',
 'ADAMTS13',
 'ADAMTS14',
 'ADAMTS15',
 'ADAMTS16',
 'ADAMTS17',
 'ADAMTS18',
 'ADAMTS19',
 'ADAMTS1',
 'ADAMTS20',
 'ADAMTS2',
 'ADAMTS3',
 'ADAMTS4',
 'ADAMTS5',
 'ADAMTS6',
 'ADAMTS7',
 'ADAMTS8',
 'ADAMTS9',
 'ADAMTSL1',
 'ADAMTSL2',
 'ADAMTSL3',
 'ADAMTSL4',
 'ADAMTSL5',
 'ADAP1',
 'ADAP2',
 'ADARB1',
 'ADARB2',
 'ADAR',
 'ADAT1',
 'ADAT2',
 'ADAT3',
 'ADA',
 'ADCK1',
 'ADCK2',
 'ADCK4',
 'ADCK5',
 'ADCY10',
 'ADCY1',
 'ADCY2',
 'ADCY3',
 'ADCY4',
 'ADCY5',
 'ADCY6',
 'ADCY7',
 'ADCY8',
 'ADCY9',
 'ADCYAP1R1',
 'ADCYAP1',
 'ADC',
 'ADD1',
 'ADD2',
 'ADD3',
 'ADH1A',
 'ADH1B',
 'ADH1C',
 'ADH4',
 'ADH5',
 'ADH6',
 'ADH7',
 'ADHFE1',
 'ADI1',
 'ADIG',
 'ADIPOQ',
 'ADIPOR1',
 'ADIPOR2',
 'ADK',
 'ADM2',
 'ADM',
 'ADNP2',
 'ADNP',
 'ADORA1',
 'ADORA2A',
 'ADORA2B',
 'ADORA3',
 'ADO',
 'ADPGK',
 'ADPRHL1',
 'ADPRHL2',
 'ADPRH',
 'ADRA1A',
 'ADRA1B',
 'ADRA1D',
 'ADRA2A',
 'ADRA2B',
 'ADRA2C',
 'ADRB1',
 'ADRB2',
 'ADRB3',
 'ADRBK1',
 'ADRBK2',
 'ADRM1',
 'ADSL',
 'ADSSL1',
 'ADSS',
 'AEBP1',
 'AEBP2',
 'AEN',
 'AES',
 'AFAP1L1',
 'AFAP1L2',
 'AFAP1',
 'AFARP1',
 'AFF1',
 'AFF2',
 'AFF3',
 'AFF4',
 'AFG3L1',
 'AFG3L2',
 'AFMID',
 'AFM',
 'AFP',
 'AFTPH',
 'AG2',
 'AGAP11',
 'AGAP1',
 'AGAP2',
 'AGAP3',
 'AGAP4',
 'AGAP5',
 'AGAP6',
 'AGAP7',
 'AGAP8',
 'AGA',
 'AGBL1',
 'AGBL2',
 'AGBL3',
 'AGBL4',
 'AGBL5',
 'AGER',
 'AGFG1',
 'AGFG2',
 'AGGF1',
 'AGK',
 'AGL',
 'AGMAT',
 'AGPAT1',
 'AGPAT2',
 'AGPAT3',
 'AGPAT4',
 'AGPAT5',
 'AGPAT6',
 'AGPAT9',
 'AGPHD1',
 'AGPS',
 'AGR2',
 'AGR3',
 'AGRN',
 'AGRP',
 'AGTPBP1',
 'AGTR1',
 'AGTR2',
 'AGTRAP',
 'AGT',
 'AGXT2L1',
 'AGXT2L2',
 'AGXT2',
 'AGXT',
 'AHCTF1',
 'AHCYL1',
 'AHCYL2',
 'AHCY',
 'AHDC1',
 'AHI1',
 'AHNAK2',
 'AHNAK',
 'AHRR',
 'AHR',
 'AHSA1',
 'AHSA2',
 'AHSG',
 'AHSP',
 'AICDA',
 'AIDA',
 'AIF1L',
 'AIF1',
 'AIFM1',
 'AIFM2',
 'AIFM3',
 'AIG1',
 'AIM1L',
 'AIM1',
 'AIM2',
 'AIMP1',
 'AIMP2',
 'AIPL1',
 'AIP',
 'AIRE',
 'AJAP1',
 'AK1',
 'AK2',
 'AK3L1',
 'AK3',
 'AK5',
 'AK7',
 'AKAP10',
 'AKAP11',
 'AKAP12',
 'AKAP13',
 'AKAP14',
 'AKAP1',
 'AKAP2',
 'AKAP3',
 'AKAP4',
 'AKAP5',
 'AKAP6',
 'AKAP7',
 'AKAP8L',
 'AKAP8',
 'AKAP9',
 'AKD1',
 'AKIRIN1',
 'AKIRIN2',
 'AKNAD1',
 'AKNA',
 'AKR1A1',
 'AKR1B10',
 'AKR1B15',
 'AKR1B1',
 'AKR1C1',
 'AKR1C2',
 'AKR1C3',
 'AKR1C4',
 'AKR1CL1',
 'AKR1D1',
 'AKR1E2',
 'AKR7A2',
 'AKR7A3',
 'AKR7L',
 'AKT1S1',
 'AKT1',
 'AKT2',
 'AKT3',
 'AKTIP',
 'ALAD',
 'ALAS1',
 'ALAS2',
 'ALB',
 'ALCAM',
 'ALDH16A1',
 'ALDH18A1',
 'ALDH1A1',
 'ALDH1A2',
 'ALDH1A3',
 'ALDH1B1',
 'ALDH1L1',
 'ALDH1L2',
 'ALDH2',
 'ALDH3A1',
 'ALDH3A2',
 'ALDH3B1',
 'ALDH3B2',
 'ALDH4A1',
 'ALDH5A1',
 'ALDH6A1',
 'ALDH7A1',
 'ALDH8A1',
 'ALDH9A1',
 'ALDOA',
 'ALDOB',
 'ALDOC',
 'ALG10B',
 'ALG10',
 'ALG11',
 'ALG12',
 'ALG13',
 'ALG14',
 'ALG1L2',
 'ALG1L',
 'ALG1',
 'ALG2',
 'ALG3',
 'ALG5',
 'ALG6',
 'ALG8',
 'ALG9',
 'ALKBH1',
 'ALKBH2',
 'ALKBH3',
 'ALKBH4',
 'ALKBH5',
 'ALKBH6',
 'ALKBH7',
 'ALKBH8',
 'ALK',
 'ALLC',
 'ALMS1P',
 'ALMS1',
 'ALOX12B',
 'ALOX12P2',
 'ALOX12',
 'ALOX15B',
 'ALOX15',
 'ALOX5AP',
 'ALOX5',
 'ALOXE3',
 'ALPI',
 'ALPK1',
 'ALPK2',
 'ALPK3',
 'ALPL',
 'ALPPL2',
 'ALPP',
 'ALS2CL',
 'ALS2CR11',
 'ALS2CR12',
 'ALS2CR4',
 'ALS2CR8',
 'ALS2',
 'ALX1',
 'ALX3',
 'ALX4',
 'AMAC1L2',
 'AMAC1L3',
 'AMAC1',
 'AMACR',
 'AMBN',
 'AMBP',
 'AMBRA1',
 'AMD1',
 'AMDHD1',
 'AMDHD2',
 'AMELX',
 'AMELY',
 'AMFR',
 'AMHR2',
 'AMH',
 'AMICA1',
 'AMIGO1',
 'AMIGO2',
 'AMIGO3',
 'AMMECR1L',
 'AMMECR1',
 'AMN1',
 'AMN',
 'AMOTL1',
 'AMOTL2',
 'AMOT',
 'AMPD1',
 'AMPD2',
 'AMPD3',
 'AMPH',
 'AMTN',
 'AMT',
 'AMY1A',
 'AMY2A',
 'AMY2B',
 'AMZ1',
 'AMZ2P1',
 'AMZ2',
 'ANAPC10',
 'ANAPC11',
 'ANAPC13',
 'ANAPC16',
 'ANAPC1',
 'ANAPC2',
 'ANAPC4',
 'ANAPC5',
 'ANAPC7',
 'ANGEL1',
 'ANGEL2',
 'ANGPT1',
 'ANGPT2',
 'ANGPT4',
 'ANGPTL1',
 'ANGPTL2',
 'ANGPTL3',
 'ANGPTL4',
 'ANGPTL5',
 'ANGPTL6',
 'ANGPTL7',
 'ANG',
 'ANK1',
 'ANK2',
 'ANK3',
 'ANKAR',
 'ANKDD1A',
 'ANKFN1',
 'ANKFY1',
 'ANKHD1-EIF4EBP3',
 'ANKHD1',
 'ANKH',
 'ANKIB1',
 'ANKK1',
 'ANKLE1',
 'ANKLE2',
 'ANKMY1',
 'ANKMY2',
 'ANKRA2',
 'ANKRD10',
 'ANKRD11',
 'ANKRD12',
 'ANKRD13A',
 'ANKRD13B',
 'ANKRD13C',
 'ANKRD13D',
 'ANKRD16',
 'ANKRD17',
 'ANKRD19',
 'ANKRD1',
 'ANKRD20A3',
 'ANKRD20A4',
 'ANKRD20B',
 'ANKRD22',
 'ANKRD23',
 'ANKRD24',
 'ANKRD26P1',
 'ANKRD26',
 'ANKRD27',
 'ANKRD28',
 'ANKRD29',
 'ANKRD2',
 'ANKRD30A',
 'ANKRD30B',
 'ANKRD31',
 'ANKRD32',
 'ANKRD33',
 'ANKRD34A',
 'ANKRD34B',
 'ANKRD34C',
 'ANKRD35',
 'ANKRD36BP1',
 'ANKRD36B',
 'ANKRD36',
 'ANKRD37',
 'ANKRD39',
 'ANKRD40',
 'ANKRD42',
 'ANKRD43',
 'ANKRD44',
 'ANKRD45',
 'ANKRD46',
 'ANKRD49',
 'ANKRD50',
 'ANKRD52',
 'ANKRD53',
 'ANKRD54',
 'ANKRD55',
 'ANKRD56',
 'ANKRD57',
 'ANKRD58',
 'ANKRD5',
 'ANKRD6',
 'ANKRD7',
 'ANKRD9',
 'ANKS1A',
 'ANKS1B',
 'ANKS3',
 'ANKS4B',
 'ANKS6',
 'ANKZF1',
 'ANLN',
 'ANO10',
 'ANO1',
 'ANO2',
 'ANO3',
 'ANO4',
 'ANO5',
 'ANO6',
 'ANO7',
 'ANO8',
 'ANO9',
 'ANP32A',
 'ANP32B',
 'ANP32C',
 'ANP32D',
 'ANP32E',
 'ANPEP',
 'ANTXR1',
 'ANTXR2',
 'ANTXRL',
 'ANUBL1',
 'ANXA10',
 'ANXA11',
 'ANXA13',
 'ANXA1',
 'ANXA2P1',
 'ANXA2P2',
 'ANXA2P3',
 'ANXA2',
 'ANXA3',
 'ANXA4',
 'ANXA5',
 'ANXA6',
 'ANXA7',
 'ANXA8L1',
 'ANXA8L2',
 'ANXA8',
 'ANXA9',
 'AOAH',
 'AOC2',
 'AOC3',
 'AOX1',
 'AOX2P',
 'AP1AR',
 'AP1B1',
 'AP1G1',
 'AP1G2',
 'AP1M1',
 'AP1M2',
 'AP1S1',
 'AP1S2',
 'AP1S3',
 'AP2A1',
 'AP2A2',
 'AP2B1',
 'AP2M1',
 'AP2S1',
 'AP3B1',
 'AP3B2',
 'AP3D1',
 'AP3M1',
 'AP3M2',
 'AP3S1',
 'AP3S2',
 'AP4B1',
 'AP4E1',
 'AP4M1',
 'AP4S1',
 'APAF1',
 'APBA1',
 'APBA2',
 'APBA3',
 'APBB1IP',
 'APBB1',
 'APBB2',
 'APBB3',
 'APC2',
 'APCDD1L',
 'APCDD1',
 'APCS',
 'APC',
 'APEH',
 'APEX1',
 'APEX2',
 'APH1A',
 'APH1B',
 'API5',
 'APIP',
 'APITD1',
 'APLF',
 'APLNR',
 'APLN',
 'APLP1',
 'APLP2',
 'APOA1BP',
 'APOA1',
 'APOA2',
 'APOA4',
 'APOA5',
 'APOB48R',
 'APOBEC1',
 'APOBEC2',
 'APOBEC3A',
 'APOBEC3B',
 'APOBEC3C',
 'APOBEC3D',
 'APOBEC3F',
 'APOBEC3G',
 'APOBEC3H',
 'APOBEC4',
 'APOB',
 'APOC1P1',
 'APOC1',
 'APOC2',
 'APOC3',
 'APOC4',
 'APOD',
 'APOE',
 'APOF',
 'APOH',
 'APOL1',
 'APOL2',
 'APOL3',
 'APOL4',
 'APOL5',
 'APOL6',
 'APOLD1',
 'APOM',
 'APOOL',
 'APOO',
 'APPBP2',
 'APPL1',
 'APPL2',
 'APP',
 'APRT',
 'APTX',
 'AQP10',
 'AQP11',
 'AQP12A',
 'AQP12B',
 'AQP1',
 'AQP2',
 'AQP3',
 'AQP4',
 'AQP5',
 'AQP6',
 'AQP7P1',
 'AQP7P3',
 'AQP7',
 'AQP8',
 'AQP9',
 'AQPEP',
 'AQR',
 'ARAF',
 'ARAP1',
 'ARAP2',
 'ARAP3',
 'ARCN1',
 'ARC',
 'AREG',
 'ARF1',
 'ARF3',
 'ARF4',
 'ARF5',
 'ARF6',
 'ARFGAP1',
 'ARFGAP2',
 'ARFGAP3',
 'ARFGEF1',
 'ARFGEF2',
 'ARFIP1',
 'ARFIP2',
 'ARFRP1',
 'ARG1',
 'ARG2',
 'ARGFXP2',
 'ARGFX',
 'ARGLU1',
 'ARHGAP10',
 'ARHGAP11A',
 'ARHGAP11B',
 'ARHGAP12',
 'ARHGAP15',
 'ARHGAP17',
 'ARHGAP18',
 'ARHGAP19',
 'ARHGAP1',
 'ARHGAP20',
 'ARHGAP21',
 'ARHGAP22',
 'ARHGAP23',
 'ARHGAP24',
 'ARHGAP25',
 'ARHGAP26',
 'ARHGAP27',
 'ARHGAP28',
 'ARHGAP29',
 'ARHGAP30',
 'ARHGAP31',
 'ARHGAP32',
 'ARHGAP33',
 'ARHGAP36',
 'ARHGAP39',
 'ARHGAP42',
 'ARHGAP4',
 'ARHGAP5',
 'ARHGAP6',
 'ARHGAP8',
 'ARHGAP9',
 'ARHGDIA',
 'ARHGDIB',
 'ARHGDIG',
 'ARHGEF10L',
 'ARHGEF10',
 'ARHGEF11',
 'ARHGEF12',
 'ARHGEF15',
 'ARHGEF16',
 'ARHGEF17',
 'ARHGEF18',
 'ARHGEF19',
 'ARHGEF1',
 'ARHGEF2',
 'ARHGEF33',
 'ARHGEF35',
 'ARHGEF37',
 'ARHGEF38',
 'ARHGEF3',
 'ARHGEF4',
 'ARHGEF5',
 'ARHGEF6',
 'ARHGEF7',
 'ARHGEF9',
 'ARID1A',
 'ARID1B',
 'ARID2',
 'ARID3A',
 'ARID3B',
 'ARID3C',
 'ARID4A',
 'ARID4B',
 'ARID5A',
 'ARID5B',
 'ARIH1',
 'ARIH2',
 'ARL10',
 'ARL11',
 'ARL13A',
 'ARL13B',
 'ARL14',
 'ARL15',
 'ARL16',
 'ARL17A',
 'ARL17B',
 'ARL1',
 'ARL2BP',
 'ARL2',
 'ARL3',
 'ARL4A',
 'ARL4C',
 'ARL4D',
 'ARL5A',
 'ARL5B',
 'ARL5C',
 'ARL6IP1',
 'ARL6IP4',
 'ARL6IP5',
 'ARL6IP6',
 'ARL6',
 'ARL8A',
 'ARL8B',
 'ARL9',
 'ARMC10',
 'ARMC1',
 'ARMC2',
 'ARMC3',
 'ARMC4',
 'ARMC5',
 'ARMC6',
 'ARMC7',
 'ARMC8',
 'ARMC9',
 'ARMCX1',
 'ARMCX2',
 ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for select rows by intersection of index:

```
b = df.loc[df.index.intersection(i)]
```

Alternative solution with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html):

```
b = df[df.index.isin(i)]
```